# How to add Multiple icons on single line string

Tags: openlayers, angular

I want to add multiple arrow on single line string with animated arrow [This Editor](https://codesandbox.io/s/feature-move-animation-forked-rvde10?file=/main.js)

I want when we click start button then add one arrow icon on line string and when we click again start button then add same new arrow icon on these line string. please see the demo application i attached link [Click Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/feature-move-animation-forked-rvde10?file=/main.js)

I was not able to code here so please click this [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/feature-move-animation-forked-rvde10?file=/main.js) and see demo application. and u also edit code here.

```
const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    features: [routeFeature, geoMarker, startMarker, endMarker],
  }),
  style: function (feature) {
    return styles[feature.get('type')];
  },
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It is not reasonable to expect others to edit your code. I strongly suggest you remove that from the Question. The way it works here, you post a complete problem statement, the relevant block of code and the complete text of the error message or other undesirable result. Graphics are encouraged for context, but code and errors should be in text form.

Comment: @TomazicM i want when we click button then add one arrow icon on line string and when we click again button then add same new arrow icon on these line string. please see the demo application i attached link in question.

Comment: @TomazicM I edits my question please explain how we can do this.

Comment: @TomazicM Please see the link i attached in question

Comment: @TomazicM Sir, the link i have added is editor's link so you are able to edit my code that's i attached a link

Comment: @TomazicM you can see my code by clicking link